# Pass array to function

Tags: c, arrays

If I have the following in C:

```
void increment_ptr(int *arr_ptr)
{   
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       arr_ptr++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int *arr_ptr = arr;

    increment_ptr(arr_ptr);
 }
```

Am I right in thinking that when I return to `main` after calling `increment_ptr`, `arr_ptr` is still pointing to `arr[0]`?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**

Because you call the function like this:

```
increment_ptr(arr_ptr);
```

This passes a copy of the pointer(pass-by-value). `arr_ptr` in `increment_ptr` is different from `arr_ptr` in `main`, although both point in the same memory location `arr`(`&arr[0]`). Modifying `arr_ptr` from the function `increment_ptr` won't affect `arr_ptr` in `main`.

For modifying `arr_ptr` in `main` from `increment_ptr`, you need to pass the address of `arr_ptr` to `increment_ptr` which is an `int**`(pointer to pointer to `int`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Functions can modify pointees, but not pointers, so to speak, since we're passing everything by value. If you want to modify `arr_ptr`, you need a pointer to a pointer, like so:

```
static void set_to_null(int** arr_ptr)
{
    *arr_ptr = 0;
}

int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int* arr_ptr = arr; // arr_ptr stores address of 'arr'
set_to_null(&arr_ptr); // arr_ptr now stores 0 (null)
```